# How to check for differences in config

Tags: drush, configuration

Is there any way to check for differences with config in Drush 8?

I checked the list of [drush 8 config commands](https://drushcommands.com/drush-8x/config) and I couldn't find anything.

The reason I need this is that I have a site that runs behat tests via CircleCI, and sometimes I need to import the configuration more than once.  So, I wanted to write a bash script that uses Drush to check whether there are any configuration differences, and if so, automatically re-imports the config in a loop until there are no more differences.

I'm stuck on Drush 8 because the behat extension only supports Drush 8.

Comment: You could probably pull in the `config:status` command from drush 9 into a module? Or use drush 8 globally, and drush 9 locally?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`drush cim --diff`

Since drush 9 there is a `diff` option that gives a diff on the config in code vs config in database

`drush cex --diff`

reverses the order of diff

Answer (score 8):

The Drush 8 commands `config:export` (cex) and `config:import` (cim) accept a `--no` to prevent the actual import or export.

This allows you to write an `if` statement in Bash. Here is an example:

```bash
if drush config:import --no | grep file.settings; then 
  # Do something
  echo "Found in diff"; 
fi
```

---

In Drush 9 and 10, the return value `$?` will tell you if there are differences between the database and the directory containing YAML files:

- 0 means no differences
- 1 means differences

Drush 9 and 10 also accept a parameter `--diff`. If there are differences, Drush will print them.

Comment: Thanks to @Gogowitsch for `--no`. I'm using the next combination for a large diffs: `drush cim --diff --no > config.diff` and then grep whatever you need.

Answer (score 3):

If you have [Drupal console](http://drupalconsole.com/commands/#) installed, you could try `config:diff`